# SQL on MIN COUNT error code 1248

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL database, I have a table named 'customer'. The task is to list the names of states with the least number of customers without displaying states with no (zero) customers.

Here is my command:

```
SELECT MIN(mycount)  
(SELECT
  state,COUNT(customerNumber) mycount
FROM customers
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY customers.state
HAVING COUNT(customerNumber) > 0);
```

But it gives an error of `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a `from` clause. Also, as the error says, you have to specify an alias for the derived table (`t` as shown below). It can be anything else as well).

```
SELECT MIN(mycount)  
from
(SELECT state,COUNT(customerNumber) mycount
FROM customers
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY customers.state
HAVING COUNT(customerNumber) > 0) t --table alias
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the states with the fewest customers, then the query should look like this

```
select state
from customers
group by state
having count(*) = (select min(cnt)
                   from (select count(*) from customers group by state) s
                  );
```

You can add `count(*)` to the outer `select` if you want the count as well.